# Overlapping relatively positioned elements in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to overlap two elements using only CSS.

So far I have found one way of doing this. I am however wondering if there are other/better ways of accomplishing this.

The only method I have found, when moving two elements closer vertically, is to subtract a bottom-margin from te bottom element. This is to account for the left over space - and then to subtract the same margin from the upper element to move it down. I have not used this method before and I wonder if it is the best way of accomplishing this overlapping effect?

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: lightgrey;
}

.bottom, .top{
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.top {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: -250px;
}

.bottom {
  padding-top:250px;
  margin-bottom: -250px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve, or what the limitations are - personally I'd use a wrapper div with `position: relative` set, then absolutely position one of the child divs within this. However, the success of this will depend greatly on your actual needs.

Comment: Using negative margins is a perfectly sound way of achieving overlapping elements, and keeping everything in flow has some benefits over using positioning and/or transforms. But the way you are using them seems unnecessarily contrived.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child--foreground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child--background">
    Background
  </div>
    <div class="child child--foreground">
    Foreground
  </div>
</div>
```

if you're trying to place an element over another, I think you should use positioning  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's more simple

```css
    body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: lightgrey;
    }
   .bottom, .top{
     width: 20%;
     padding-bottom: 20%;
   }
   .top {
     background: blue;
   }
   .bottom { 
     background: red; 
     border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
     padding-top: 250px;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
   }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```